# information about fonts of qt

Tags: fonts, qt-creator

I'm trying some infromation about fonts in qt but can't find, can somebody please help me, I'm working with the last qt-creator, how does it work, qt-creator has some fonts from inside program, or it depends on fonts on my PC, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Qt uses fonts installed on your system. See [QFont](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qfont.html) and related classes in the Qt documentation for details.